# The [.] only matches periods

Tags: javascript, regex

This is tested in JavaScript.

I'm looking through a regex for an email, and found this as a part of the expression:

`[-+.']`

I though that the `.` should be changed to `\.`, but when I tested `[.]` it only matches periods, just like `\.`would. In abc.abc@abc.com only the periods are matched.

How come? Shouldn't it match any character except line break?

And, can someone explain how grouping with `( )` works versus `[ ]` while we are at it?
I got a bit confused. Thanks!

Comment: What is the programming language where you are trying to apply regex?

Comment: Please ask only one thing at a time. For two separate questions, create two separate SO questions. Otherwise, selecting the best answers for both of your questions may not be possible, unless they happen to appear in the same SO answer.

Comment: Inside the `[]` character class, `.` is a literal, not a metacharacter.

Comment: @AlexStamper This is tested in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.` only matches the literal period because you're using it inside a class.

`[...]` is not a group, it's a character class, and it'll match any character out from that class once, you can think of it as an `or`, meaning that:

`[-+.']` will match `-` or `+` or `.` or `'`

On the other hand `(...)` defines a capturing group, meaning that the match inside it will be grouped and "saved" for later use.

If you only want to group the match, not use it later, you can use a non-capturing group, with the syntax: `(? ... )`

Answer (score 3):

**()** is subpattern for regular expression.

**[]** is used as character class or character set.

You can tell the regex engine to match only one out of several characters. Simply place the characters you want to match between square brackets. If you want to match an **a** or an **e**, use **[ae]**. You could use this in **gr[ae]y** to match either gray or grey.

here you will find good tutorial

http://www.regular-expressions.info/

> **[-+.']** - matches 1 character either - or + or . or ' you can use for example
>
> **[-+.']{2}** to match 2 characters in this group or
>
> **[-+.']*** to match 0 or more characters or
>
> **[-+.']+** to match 1 or more characters

dot in **[]** has different meaning than dot not in **[]**.

The dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is. The only exception are newline characters. In **[]** dot means dot ;)

Comment: Voted up, saw what I was looking for already on the top, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A square bracket expression isn't "grouping", it's a *character class* which matches any single character out of the set listed inside the brackets.  Inside square brackets most metacharacters are treated as literals, so `[.*]` would match a single character which is either a dot or a star.

Parentheses (`()`) are for grouping and capturing.  `(.*)` would match any sequence of zero or more characters, and would store the matched string in a buffer for future reference, typically either as a backreference later in the match pattern (e.g. `(a*)b\1` matches zero or more `a` characters, then a b, then *the same number* of a's again) or a reference in a replacement string.  Exactly what the syntax is for this depends on the programming language you're using.

Comment: Voted up, saw what I was looking for already on the top, thanks!